# ¿Por qué me da error al editar la URL de devolución de llamada en los webhooks de Messenger?

Tags: facebook, webhook

He desarrollado un chatbot en Messenger con Node y Dialogflow.
Tenía desplegada una api en Heroku en la cual  tenía el endpoint para la devolución de llamada y se conectaba al webhook en Messenger.
Funcionaba bien hasta que heroku dejó de ser gratuito. Entonces desplegué la api en Railway pero al tratar de cambiar la URL de devolución de
llamada me muestra el error:

> "La URL https://.../messenger/webhook se identificó como maliciosa o abusiva"

Al editar la suscripción en la sección de webhooks y otro error en la sección Messenger - Configurar que dice:

> "Error No se pudo validar la URL de devolución de llamada o el token de verificación. Comprueba la información proporcionada o vuelve a intentarlo más tarde."

No logro solucionar. La api funciona bien para mi aplicación web, pero falla para Messenger.
Probé haciendo una petición get con Postman y me retorna un status 200. Bien al parecer.

Adjunto imágenes de los errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Se que ya ha pasado mucho tiempo y el tema podría estar olvidado, pero les comento que luego de ver que me ocurrió a mí me di cuenta de que fue.

Sucede que facebook para validar siempre va a esperar que el token que envía se retorne, de este modo él va a enviar el token y busca que ese token se retorne tal cual para validarse con el que tienes en back y el que mandó facebook.

Por consiguiente si tienes cosas que están retornando antes deberás moverlas de posición y hacer que el token sea lo primero que cuando se inicia la app se solicite en el back.

```
if(myToken == itsToken) {
  return myToken
}
```

Saludos.